# show validation errors line by line

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I use ajax call to display validation errors generated by Codeigniter on the view.

**controller:**

```
$error = strip_tags(validation_errors());         
$data = array('message' => $error);
echo json_encode($data);
```

**I get following line from console network:**

```
{"message":"The First Name field is required.\nThe Last Name field is required.\n"}
```

**JS file:**

```
 $( "#error").text(data.message);
```

**and I get following line on my view:**

```
The First Name field is required. The Last Name field is required.
```

**but I want it to be displayed in the following way:**

```
The First Name field is required. 

The Last Name field is required.
```

Could you please help me to style my view.

Comment: Use nl2br on $error before encoding.

Comment: great. and what if I want to insert 2 br tags between each line?

Comment: then you can use str_replace, or regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`, Try this:

```
 $( "#error").html(data.message.replace(/\n/, '<br>'));
```

You can split messages and get an array:

```
 var messages = data.message.split("\n"));
 for(var i=0; i<messages.length;i++)
     $( "#error").append(messages[i] + '<br/><br/>');
```

Comment: The First Name field is required. <br> The Last Name field is required.

Comment: Use html() function instead of text() function

Comment: it works now. but what if there are several errors. it inserts br only between first and second rows

Answer (score 0):

In js file :

```
var data_message = data.message.split('\n');

$( "#error").html(data_message[0] +"<br />"+ data_message[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the Error Delimiters**

By default, the Form Validation class adds a paragraph tag (

) around each error message shown. You can either change these delimiters globally or individually.

**1-Changing delimiters Globally**

To globally change the error delimiters, in your controller function, just after loading the Form Validation class, add this:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

**2-Changing delimiters Individually**

```
<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

**or**

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

in this  case i dont know why you **strip_tags** ,it will remove all html,php, from the return string ,

so how could you style with out tags ?!!!

[CodeIgniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters)